# How can I nix-env install a derivation from a nix expression file?

Tags: nix, nixos

I've got a `default.nix` file that builds a derivation (at least my understanding of it).

```
{ nixpkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {}, compiler ? "ghc864" } :
nixpkgs.pkgs.haskell.packages.${compiler}.callCabal2nix "bhoogle" (./.) {}
```

I can successfully `nix-build` this. Is there a way I can install this into my user profile with `nix-env` directly? For example something like `nix-env -i -f default.nix`.

Otherwise I need to define a package in my system profile with something like:

```
  example = pkgs.callPackage /home/chris/example/default.nix {};
```

Comment: Your example `nix-env` invocation looks fine. Did you try it?

Comment: It works! I think I read the nix-env --help for `-f` and just dismissed it as not what I was looking for - but apparently not! Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Quite literally my initial guess (thanks @Robert):

```
nix-env -i -f default.nix
```

Documented in `nix --help`:

> ```
>    --file / -f path
>        Specifies the Nix expression (designated below as the active Nix expression) used by the --install, --upgrade, and --query
> ```
>
> --available operations to obtain
>              derivations. The default is ~/.nix-defexpr.
>
> ```
>        If the argument starts with http:// or https://, it is interpreted as the URL of a tarball that will be downloaded and
> ```
>
> unpacked to a temporary location. The tarball
>              must include a single top-level directory containing at least a file named default.nix.